# Can anyone explain this weird issue copying data into a chart?

Tags: excel, vba, graph

I have a macro that copies select data from one worksheet to another. From that worksheet it takes the data and copies it into a chart. Despite my macro designating the source data  that goes into the chart, it doesn't pull it all in.

I'm running Windows 7. I have two coworkers that are running Windows 10 that do not have this issue. Exact same code. Creates the exact same source data. However my version doesn't pull in all of the source data. Theirs does. I'm not understanding why.

Below is the code:

```
Sub graph_creator()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual

Dim cf As Worksheet
Dim CF_lrow As Long

Dim graphdata As Worksheet
Dim ptr As Long
Dim i As Long

Dim graph_ws As Worksheet
Dim graph_lrow As Long
Dim graph As Chart

Set cf = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Cashflow with Payment Schedule")
Set graphdata = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Graph Data")

CF_lrow = cf.Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row
graphdata.Rows(2 & ":" & Rows.Count).EntireRow.Delete

For ptr = 2 To CF_lrow - 28
    graphdata.Cells(ptr, 1).Formula = "='Cashflow with Payment Schedule'!F" & (ptr + 28)
    graphdata.Cells(ptr, 2).Formula = "='Cashflow with Payment Schedule'!J" & (ptr + 28)
    graphdata.Cells(ptr, 3).Formula = "='Cashflow with Payment Schedule'!H" & ptr + 27
Next

i = 29

For ptr = CF_lrow - 27 To (CF_lrow - 27) * 2 - 2
    graphdata.Cells(ptr, 1).Formula = "='Cashflow with Payment Schedule'!F" & i
    graphdata.Cells(ptr, 3).Formula = "='Cashflow with Payment Schedule'!H" & i
    graphdata.Cells(ptr, 2).Formula = "='Cashflow with Payment Schedule'!J" & i
    i = i + 1
Next

Set graph = cf.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart
graph_lrow = graphdata.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
graph.SetSourceData Source:=graphdata.Range("A1:C" & graph_lrow)

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic

End Sub
```

Both of our versions create this source data:
[image: Source Data]

However, my graph appears as this: [image: My Graph]

And their graph appears as this: [image: Their Graph]

Again, we're all using the same exact code. How come my code doesn't pull in all of the source data as theirs does. Also notice the dates on their graph.

Comment: I believe you should be able to right click on a graph to view the source data. Have you tried checking the row **below** the _last included_ row to see if there's anything significantly different about that data (which may have caused the macro to believe there wasn't anymore)?

Comment: The dates on your coworkers graphs aren't dates, they're the numbers 1 through 30 (or so) formatted as dates.  That's just counting the data points.

Comment: Also, just from glancing, the source data looks like all but one of the rows are duplicated... just FYI

Comment: @Mistella, yes. The data is duplicated. That's going to be changing, but looking into the issue of why my graph only pulls in the data starting at A12 rather than A2.

Answer (score 1):

Your graph is correct, and your coworkers' graph is not.  Here's why:

Your data set has two overlapping sequences, covering roughly the same curve in the same year.

Your coworkers graphs are showing all the Y values in order, without regard to the X values.  This is incorrect.

The default graph type on your coworkers' machine is not the same as yours, so when you pass the generic graph to Excel over the three columns without telling Excel what to do with the three columns, the defaults of the program define the graph.

Set the [ChartType property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/chart-charttype-property-excel) of the chart as shown [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/xlcharttype-enumeration-excel).  That should clear it up!

Comment: Yes, my version is correct. We're trying to understand why their graphs aren't displaying the same as mine despite the code being the same. I'm using Excel 2010 on Windows 7 and they're on 2016 on Windows 10.

Comment: Their charttype is wrong... yours is some kind of XY graph, their is some kind of bar graph or line graph that doesn't care about X.